# Why doesn't the Earlier function work when used within my row context

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am trying to create a rolling sum from the results of a calculation between two values (`object_1` and `object_2`). The problem is when i try to achieve this by using the `calculate` function + the `earlier` function, it doesn't seem to have any affect.

I have tried creating a virtual table with the values i am trying to create a rolling sum out of (using `Summarize`), then using `earlier` in a `Sumx` function to create the desired effect but this did not work.

```
Rolling Sum = 

var object_1 = Calculate(SUM('Table 1'[Value]),
   Filter(allselected('Table 1'),
      COUNTROWS(FILTER('Table 1',
         EARLIER('Table 1'[Date])<= 'Table 1'[Date]))))

var object_2 = Calculate(SUM('Table 2'[Value]),
   Filter(allselected('Table 2'),
      COUNTROWS(FILTER('Table 2',
         EARLIER('Table 2'[Date])<= 'Table 2'[Date]))))

return

calculate(object_1 - object_2,
   Filter(allselected('Date Table'),
      COUNTROWS(FILTER('Date Table',
         EARLIER('Date Table'[Date])<= 'Date Table'[Date]))))
```

The desired results would be a rolling sum of all the dates equal to or below the date.

The results am getting are the same as `object_1 - object_2` without the `calculation` function's filter

Comment: This is an example I think you can use to create your rolling calculation. It calculates the fractional change from 6 month rolling current year compared with previous year:
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53699112/create-6-months-rolling-average-on-week-filter/53757249#53757249)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe since you are using EARLIER in a VAR it is taken outside of the filter context which is basically ignoring it. You may have some luck moving your calculations inside of the return statement and then just creating a VAR to store you max date (which is taken outside of the filter context).. I haven't tested this but maybe something like:

```
    Rolling Sum =
VAR T1MaxDate =
    MAX ( 'Table 1'[Date] )
VAR T2MaxDate =
    MAX ( 'Table 2'[Date] )
VAR MaxDate =
    MAX ( 'Date Table'[Date] )
RETURN
    CALCULATE (
        CALCULATE (
            SUM ( 'Table 1'[Value] ),
            FILTER (
                ALLSELECTED ( 'Table 1' ),
                COUNTROWS ( FILTER ( 'Table 1', 'Table 1'[Date] <= T1MaxDate ) )
            )
        )
            - CALCULATE (
                SUM ( 'Table 2'[Value] ),
                FILTER (
                    ALLSELECTED ( 'Table 2' ),
                    COUNTROWS ( FILTER ( 'Table 2', 'Table 2'[Date] <= T2MaxDate ) )
                )
            ),
        FILTER (
            ALLSELECTED ( 'Date Table' ),
            COUNTROWS ( FILTER ( 'Date Table', 'Date Table'[Date] <= MaxDate ) )
        )
    )
```

Comment: Quick question; in the last filter context did you mean table 2 instead of date 2?? and if so why?

Comment: I based this off of your original measure which is filtering 'Date 2' but I think that was unintended so I edited my post.

Comment: @KvothesLute see my edits, this is a pretty standard pattern and should get you what you need. If you need ALLSELECTED() you can always build off of the measure

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, i got it now. Is it better to use this way of doing this rather than earlier?

Comment: @KvothesLute I guess you found your solution :) Glad it worked out for you

Comment: if the original solution worked I'll revert my post

Comment: I didnt mean your solution didnt work for me, it did and it's the one i am using. Was just wondering if Earlier was not the best function for this kind of task

Comment: aw ok gotcha! Earlier is fine as long as you know when and where to use it. Vars can create some unintended results so you just have to be aware of the filter context.